# python на vds неправильно записывает данные в txt

Tags: python, файлы

Есть парсер, который хранит считанные id в old-ids.txt
При запуске через ide все работает нормально, id пишутся через строку
Вот фрагмент, записывающий id:

```
history.write(str(offered.attrib.get('internal-id')) + "\n")
```

Вот что записывается в txt, если запустить в ide:

```
python3 parser.py

3198935
3198935
2739143
2268209
2882363
```

А это записывается в файл, если запущу на vds на ubuntu 16.04

```
3269705324444228660343338970
```

Как вы видите, \n просто игнорится при записи. Я в отчаянии

Comment: Выведите в print содержимое файла `print(open(<file_name>, 'rb').read())` для вот этого результата `3269705324444228660343338970` и добавьте в вопрос

Comment: @gil9red сменил формат хранения, теперь через запятую хранятся :)))

Comment: Почему бы и нет, хех :) Но интересно было бы разобраться, почему на убунте по другому

Comment: Наверное пробовал открывать виндовым блокнотом. Он игнорит перенос по \n